# Problem with realloc in C. I tried to built a vector dynamically, the output is correct but valgrind suggest me that there are problems in memory

Tags: c

Hello everybody I have a problem with this code. I have to return a vector make up of the elements of the matrix without  repetitions(the matrix should be read by colons)
. The output is correct but valgrind suggest me that there are problems in memory. I tried to built the vector dynamically, adding a new element through the realloc.
Thank u so much.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void printa_matrice(int nc, int nr , int ** mat)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<nr; i++){
        for(j=0; j<nc ; j++){
            printf("(%d)", mat[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
}

int  its_new(int elem ,int * ptr, int conta)
{
    int new=1;
    int i ;
    for(i=0; i<conta; i++){
        if(ptr[i]== elem){
            new =0;
        }
    }
    return new;
}
void print_vect(int conta, int * ptr)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<conta; i++){
        printf("%d, ", ptr[i]);
    }
    puts("");
}

int* matrix_to_vec(int nr, int nc , int ** mat)
{
    int conta=0;
    int *V;
    V= malloc(sizeof(int));
    int i,j;

    for(j=0; j<nc; j++){
        for(i=0; i<nr; i++){
            if (its_new(mat[i][j],V,conta ))
            {
                V[conta]= mat[i][j];
                conta=conta+1;
                V= realloc(V,conta* sizeof(int));
            }
        }
    }
    print_vect(conta, V);
    return V;
}

int main()
{
    int nc=3;
    int nr=3;
    int **mat;
    int i ;

    mat=(int **)malloc(nr*sizeof(int*));
    mat[0]=(int *)malloc(nr*nc*sizeof(int));
    for(i=1; i<nr; i++)
    {
        mat[i]= mat[0] + i*nc;
    }

    mat[0][0]=4;
    mat[0][1]=-1;
    mat[0][2]=4;
    mat[1][0]=5;
    mat[1][1]=-1;
    mat[1][2]=5;
    mat[2][0]=4;
    mat[2][1]=4;
    mat[2][2]=0;

    printa_matrice(nc, nr, mat);
    int * headV;
    headV = matrix_to_vec(nr, nc, mat);
    free(mat[0]);
    free(mat);
    free(headV);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So initially, `conta=0` and `V` has size `sizeof(int)`. After the first `realloc`, `conta=1` and `V` size has changed to `1*sizeof(int)`, **which is the same size as before!**

Comment: thank you so  much !

Answer (score 0):

In `matrix_to_vec`:

```
        if (its_new(mat[i][j],V,conta ))
        {
            V[conta]= mat[i][j];
            conta=conta+1;
            V= realloc(V,conta* sizeof(int));
        }
```

When you call `realloc`, you're not giving enough space for the new element.  `conta` starts at 0.  So when you increment and reallocate, `conta` is 1 which is the same as the original size.

Since `conta` is the index of the last element, you want to add 1 to that when reallocating.

```
            V= realloc(V, (conta+1) * sizeof(int));
```